# How do i colorplot a circle, but exclude the color of the area contained in some other circle

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

If I have 2 circles, I know their radius and their centerpoints, how do i colorplot the area of some circle, but exclude the color in the other circle (not plotting it white)? I'm familiar with matplotlib.pyplot, however I can't seem to figure out this one.

See following figure for examples:

[Some sample cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZIGW.png)

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `numpy` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Comment: SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not doing it for you. At least show what you got so far and how it misses to achieve your goals.
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim (word for word) into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# x and y is the centerpoint and r is the radius
circle1 = plt.Circle((x1, y1), r1, edgecolor='b', facecolor='r')
circle2 = plt.Circle((x2, y2), r2, edgecolor='b', facecolor='w')
circle3 = plt.Circle((x1, y1), r1, color='b', fill=False)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_artist(circle1)
ax.add_artist(circle2)
ax.add_artist(circle3)
fig.show()
```

To change the appearance of your circles there are many arguemnts you can pass to the circle object. Check out the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html) for more info